# Ao invés do comando ajax ficar na página, ele está sendo direcionado a página php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

```
   $('#formCadastrarProdutos').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: '../crud/cadastro_produtos.php',
        type: 'post',
        data:  new FormData(this),            
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "erronome"){
               $('.erronome').html('Produto já cadastrado.');
            }else{
                alert('Produto cadastrado com sucesso!');
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }        
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancele o evento `submit` com `preventDefault()`:

```
//                  inclua o parâmetro na função que retorna o evento
//                                          ↓
$('#formCadastrarProdutos').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // cancela o evento

    $.ajax({
    url: '../crud/cadastro_produtos.php',
    type: 'post',
    data:  new FormData(this),            
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        if(data == "erronome"){
           $('.erronome').html('Produto já cadastrado.');
        }else{
            alert('Produto cadastrado com sucesso!');
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }        
    });
});
```

Observe também que nesta linha...

```
window.location.reload();
```

...a página está sendo recarregada. Se não for esta a intenção, basta removê-la.